# What could be causing db.SubmitChanges() to not work in linq-to-sql?

Tags: wpf, linq-to-sql, submitchanges

I've set up a very simple example with LINQ-TO-SQL in WPF.

I can get an **object** (pageItem) out like this and I can change the **property** and when I call **SubmitChanges**() it gives me **no error** but it **doesn't save** the change.

```
MainDataContext db = new MainDataContext();
var pageItem = (from p in db.PageItems
              where p.Id == 1
              select p).SingleOrDefault();

pageItem.Title = "changed";
db.SubmitChanges();
```

**What could be causing SubmitChanges not to submit the changes?**

## MORE INFO:

This doesn't work either, even the db.ExecuteCommand doesn't work, and strangely when debugging F11 doesn't step into SubmitChanges() or ExecuteCommand(), why can't I step in those?

```
using (var db = new MainDataContext())
{
    var pageItem = (from p in db.PageItems
                    where p.Id == 1
                    select p).SingleOrDefault();

    pageItem.Title = "changed";
    db.SubmitChanges();

    db.ExecuteCommand("INSERT INTO PageItems (Title) VALUES ('this is the title')");


    if (pageItem != null)
        MainContent.Children.Add(new QuickForm(pageItem));

}
```

## more info:

The db.Log = Console.Out gives me this:

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[IdCode], [t0].[Title], [t0].[Description], [t0].[DisplayOrder]
FROM [dbo].[PageItems] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Id] = @p0
'TestPageManager23434.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework.resources\3.0.0.0_de_31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.resources.dll'
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = 0; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [1]
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.30729.1

INSERT INTO PageItems (Title) VALUES ('this is the title')
-- Context: SqlProvider(Sql2008) Model: AttributedMetaModel Build: 3.5.30729.1

The thread 0x1190 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

## ANSWER

The solution was three-fold:

- I was changing a different database than I was looking at in visual studio, solution:

  var db = new MainDataContext(@"C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\TestPageManager23434\TestPageManager23434\Data\Main.mdf"))
- that made Update work but not SubmitChanges(), solution was to set the primary key.
- it still wasn't showing all the chagnes, problem was I had a number of "show data" windows open which weren't being updated

Comment: Are you sure that the pageItem.Title wasn't "changed" to start with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can happen if you don't have a primary key defined on the tables in SQL Server

Comment: This bit me once - I'd submit changes, never get an exception, and it would go on its merry way, but never actually make it into the DB.  All because I didn't specify, in the table, what my primary key was.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using SQL Expression mdf file?

There's an [article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/70751a17-666f-4f2e-ab16-5a42285e93a3/) about how this might cause you to get a copy of the file and not the original, causing the symptoms you're describing.

FTA:

> I think the project system or server
>   explorer wizard offers to 'copy' your
>   mdf into your project directory. 
>   Maybe you are operating on a copy of
>   the database and viewing the other in
>   server explorer.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason the context may not be tracking changes.  Try wiring up your `db.Log` to a writer and inspect what LINQ->SQL is doing when you call `SubmitChanges()`..

```
db.Log = Console.Out;
```

Then you can watch your output window running in debug and see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in which the record in the **Database** I see in my project was not modified by the `SubmitChanges` method.

After so many trial and researches I found out that the system put another version of the **Database** `Northwnd.mdf` in the project's root directory `\Bin\Debug\Northwnd.mdf`. That is where the changes, perfectly, occurred.